# How to do a SQL grouping by multiple columns including days

Tags: sql, performance, firebird

I have the following table which holds the working hours for each worker and for each workplace:

```
CREATE TABLE WAGES_HOURS (
  ID LONGID NOT NULL,  
  -- Table's Abstract Primary Key
  WORKERID LONGID NOT NULL, 
  -- The FK for the Worker
  MONTHID ID NOT NULL, 
  -- The month: 1 - January, 2 - Feb., ..., 12 - Dec.
  PLACEID LONGID NOT NULL, 
  -- The FK for the Workplace
  D01 HOURS, 
  -- how many hours worker worked in the workplace in the Day 1. 
  -- A value of 0 means no work.
  D02 HOURS, 
  -- the same for the Day 2  ...and so on till the last day of month (D31)
  D03 HOURS,      D04 HOURS,      D05 HOURS,      D06 HOURS,      D07 HOURS,
  D08 HOURS,      D09 HOURS,      D10 HOURS,      D11 HOURS,      D12 HOURS,
  D13 HOURS,      D14 HOURS,      D15 HOURS,      D16 HOURS,      D17 HOURS,
  D18 HOURS,      D19 HOURS,      D20 HOURS,      D21 HOURS,      D22 HOURS,
  D23 HOURS,      D24 HOURS,      D25 HOURS,      D26 HOURS,      D27 HOURS,
  D28 HOURS,      D29 HOURS,      D30 HOURS,     D31 HOURS);
```

From this data we want to show one or two report(s) for a concrete month (entered in GUI) which will show:

- how many workers worked in each day in each workplace
- (optional) the sum of hours for each worker in each day in each workplace

I cannot figure how to do it in the best way - till now I have 31 queries which do the grouping for each day - something like this:

```
select COUNT(workerid), placeid 
from wages_hours 
where monthid=:myMonth and d01>0 
group by placeid;
```

...but I feel that it is possible a better way.

Does someone know it?

PS: The database backend is Firebird 2.5, if matters

Comment: If you're counting actual rows (like you are here), placing a column into the `COUNT(...)` function has no effect.  You can do the count of workers in one query (search for `SUM(CASE WHEN...)`).  What did you mean for the other part - can we get sample starting and target data and query you've tried?  I'm having trouble parsing your description.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of bad structure of DB.

You can change your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE WAGES_HOURS (
  ID LONGID NOT NULL,  -- Table's Abstract Primary Key
  WORKERID LONGID NOT NULL, -- The FK for the Worker
  MONTHID ID NOT NULL, -- The month: 1 - January, 2 - Feb., ..., 12 - Dec.
  PLACEID LONGID NOT NULL, -- The FK for the Workplace
  Hours HOURS, -- how many hours worker worked in the workplace in the Day 1. 
  -- A value of 0 means no work.
  Day int,
 CONSTRAINT Day CHECK (Day>0 and Day<32)
  );
```

How how many workers worked in each day in each workplace

```
SELECT Day, PlaceID,Count() FROM Wages_Hours group by Day, PlaceID
```

OR

You may use `UNPIVOT` function like this. Not sure if it works on Firebird.

```
SELECT ID, WorkerID, PlaceID, MonthID, Hours, Days
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM Wages_Hours) p
UNPIVOT
   (Hours FOR Days IN 
      (D01, D02,.... ,D31)
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: I cannot change it. There are other factors / requirements in place. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: I'm with you - the design should be changed if possible. Though if you're going to change it, you could at least make the resulting time dimension an actual `DATE`.

Comment: @MikkaRin Firebird doesn't have `UNPIVOT`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to take the approach described in [the answer by MikkaRinn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22064607/466862). However as you indicate that you can't change the current structure of the table, I propose a different solution.

For any easy manipulation of the data, you should unpivot the data. Unfortunately Firebird does not have an `UNPIVOT`-clause, so you need to simulate this using a selectable procedure and dynamically built queries executed using [`EXECUTE STATEMENT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forexec).

For example you could use the following stored procedures (with all of your domains replaced by `INTEGER` so I could easily test the implementation):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE UNPIVOT_WAGES_HOURS 
RETURNS 
 ( 
    ID Integer, 
    WORKERID Integer, 
    MONTHID Integer, 
    PLACEID Integer,
    DAYINMONTH Integer,
    HOURS Integer
 )
AS 
DECLARE VARIABLE dayCount Integer;
DECLARE VARIABLE dayColumn VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE VARIABLE query VARCHAR(1500);
BEGIN
  dayCount = 1;
  WHILE (dayCount <= 31) DO
  BEGIN
    dayColumn = 'D' || LPAD(CAST(dayCount AS VARCHAR(2)), 2, '0');
    query = 'SELECT ID, WORKERID, MONTHID, PLACEID, ' || dayCount || 
            ' AS DAYINMONTH, ' || dayColumn || ' AS HOURS FROM WAGES_HOURS';
    
    FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT query 
        INTO :ID, :WORKERID, :MONTHID, :PLACEID, :DAYINMONTH, :HOURS
    DO
        SUSPEND;
    
    dayCount = dayCount + 1;
  END
END
```

For each day column, this stored procedure constructs a dynamic query with the column name, executes it into the return 'columns' and uses `SUSPEND` to return every individual row to the caller. This executes 31 individual `SELECT` statements per stored procedure execution, so it might not perform that well on large datasets.

Executing this stored procedure is done as:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.WORKERID, p.MONTHID, p.PLACEID, p.DAYINMONTH, p.HOURS
FROM UNPIVOT_WAGES_HOURS p
```

A selectable stored procedure can be used the same as a table or view reference. Depending on the required processing of the data it might be worth inserting into a temporary table before doing more with it.

### Addendum: single query solution

It is possible to create a single query unpivot stored procedure, but it requires mapping all 31 day columns to individual local variables, and for every row do 31 `SUSPEND`s. Eg something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE UNPIVOT_WAGES_HOURS2 
RETURNS 
 ( 
    ID Integer, 
    WORKERID Integer, 
    MONTHID Integer, 
    PLACEID Integer,
    DAYINMONTH Integer,
    HOURS Integer
 )
AS 
    DECLARE VARIABLE D01 Integer;
    DECLARE VARIABLE D02 Integer;
    /*...*/
    DECLARE VARIABLE D30 Integer;
    DECLARE VARIABLE D31 Integer;
BEGIN
    FOR SELECT ID, WORKERID, MONTHID, PLACEID, D01, D02, /*...*/ D30, D31
        FROM WAGES_HOURS
        INTO :ID, :WORKERID, :MONTHID, :PLACEID, :D01, :D02, /*...*/ :D30, :D31
    DO
    BEGIN
       DAYINMONTH = 1;
       HOURS = D01;
       SUSPEND;
       DAYINMONTH = 2;
       HOURS = D02;
       SUSPEND;
       /*...*/
       DAYINMONTH = 30;
       HOURS = D30;
       SUSPEND;
       DAYINMONTH = 31;
       HOURS = D31;
       SUSPEND;
    END
END
```

It might perform better, but one slip of the keyboard and you inadvertently return the wrong values or a day twice and another not at all.